# Creating dplyr function with passing column argument

Tags: r, function, dplyr, col

I am trying to pass column name as argument to a function which uses dplyr functions within.

There were multiple questions already asked around this theme and I tried all of them, everything seems to throw some or the other error.

I used enquo with !! as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466577/passing-column-names-through-multiple-functions-with-dplyr). Tried using !! as_label to combat the error I got from the previous step using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406546/how-to-fix-quosures-can-only-be-unquoted-within-a-quasiquotation-context-error). Also tried to use group_by_ instead of group_by as mentioned [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/data-frame-columns-as-arguments-to-dplyr-functions/). I have also tried the curly operator for resolution

```
userMaster <- structure(list(user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), city = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Austin", "Boise", "Boston", "Chicago", 
"Dallas", "Denver", "Detroit", "Kansas City", "Las Vegas", "Los Angeles", 
"Manhattan", "Miami", "Minneapolis", "New York City", "Oklahoma City", 
"Omaha", "Phoenix", "Saint Louis", "San Francisco", "Washington DC"
), class = "factor"), source = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Adwords", "Organic", "Search Ads"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

userCount <- function(table, metric){
  col_enquo <- enquo(metric)

  summary <- table %>% select(!! (col_enquo), source, user_id) %>%
    group_by_(!! (col_enquo), source) %>% summarise(users = n_distinct(user_id)) %>% 
    left_join(table %>% group_by(source) %>% 
                summarise(total = n_distinct(user_id))) %>% mutate(users/total)
  return(summary)
}

genderDemo <- userCount(userMaster, city)
```

I get every type of error -

```
Error: `quos(desire)` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list

Error in !as_label(col_enquo) : invalid argument type 

Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.

  # Bad:
  list(!!myquosure)

  # Good:
  dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013409/how-to-summarize-with-multiple-outputs-a-column-in-a-dataset-by-groups-efficie/57013655#57013655

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `rlang_0.4.0`, we can use `{{...}}` (curly-curly operator)   which can do the evaluation simpler

```
library(rlang) #v 0.4.0
library(dplyr) #v 0.8.3
userCount <- function(tbl, metric){
  
  tbl %>% 
       select({{metric}}, source, user_id) %>%
       group_by({{metric}}, source) %>% 
       summarise(users = n_distinct(user_id)) %>% 
       left_join(tbl %>% 
                group_by(source) %>% 
                summarise(total = n_distinct(user_id))) %>% 
                 mutate(users/total)

   }

genderDemo <- userCount(userMaster, desire)
genderDemo
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   desire [4]
#   desire source users total `users/total`
#   <fct>  <fct>  <int> <int>         <dbl>
# 1 A      a          2     4         0.5  
# 2 A      b          1     3         0.333
# 3 A      c          2     5         0.4  
# 4 B      a          1     4         0.25 
# 5 B      b          1     3         0.333
# 6 B      c          1     5         0.2  
# 7 C      a          1     4         0.25 
# 8 C      b          2     3         0.667
# 9 C      c          1     5         0.2  
#10 D      a          1     4         0.25 
#11 D      b          1     3         0.333
#12 D      c          2     5         0.4
```

Using OP's data

```
userCount(userMaster2, city)
#Joining, by = "source"
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   city [4]
#  city        source  users total `users/total`
#  <fct>       <fct>   <int> <int>         <dbl>
#1 Dallas      Organic     2     5           0.4
#2 Kansas City Organic     1     5           0.2
#3 Las Vegas   Organic     1     5           0.2
#4 Los Angeles Organic     1     5           0.2
```

NOTE: `-` suffix method is getting deprecated.  So, either use `{{..}}` in `group_by` or `group_by(!! enquo(col_enquo))`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
userMaster <- data.frame(desire = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 5),
                        user_id = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
                        source = sample(letters[1:3], 20, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: @Krithi07  Can you also update with a small reproducible example using `dput`.  In that way, I can test

Comment: Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'desire' not found

Comment: This was the error I had gotten when I used the curl braces

Comment: @Krithi07  Could you please update your question with an example or do you want me to guess

Comment: Not sure I can dput the data here. It's client's data :(

Comment: @Krithi07  I don't need your client's data.  Just some data that mimics the structure

Comment: @Krithi07  Can you check the updated posst with the output.  In your example, theere is no `desire` column, so I am using `city`

Comment: I'm getting the same error I mentioned earlier,  Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'desire' not found

Comment: @Krithi07  Are you using the updated function `select({{metric}}, source, user_id)` earlier without testing i had `select(metric, source, user_id)`

Comment: @Krithi07  I noticed that your object name is same `userMaster` as the data I used.  I changed your data to a diffeerent name.  If you noticed that

Comment: I even tried using this function using the data you created in the post. Still giving me the same error

Comment: @Krithi07  Okay, then I can't replicate your issue.  I am using `rlang 0.4.0` and `dplyr_0.8.3`

Comment: Version was the problem. I upgraded and everything's working fine now. Thanks